# Check null or empty IEnumerable<double> in C#

Tags: c#, math.net

What is the best way to check `null` or empty for `IEnumerable<double>` in C#?

What I have tried so far is

```
return returnList != null && returnList.Any();
```

but I get a message that this expression will always return `true`.

Full method:

```
public double ArithmeticMean(IEnumerable<double> ReturnsList, bool IsMonthly)
{
    var returnList = ReturnsList.Mean();

    if (IsMonthly)
    {
        return returnList;
    }
    else
    {
        return returnList * Math.Pow(12, 0.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: That probably means it cannot be null.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We don't have enough information to help you at the moment.

Comment: We don't have enough information, but at a guess I'm assuming you are using Resharper and it's telling you that `returnList` is not null so you have a redundant check.

Comment: if returnList is a simple IEnumerable<double> then it should work. Show us the code before that.

Comment: Is `.Mean()` and extension method? Can you show the definition?

Comment: Yes. I am using Math.Net library

Comment: But before that i need to check if ReturnsList is null or empty

Comment: from the shown code we can't help you much. From my perspective null or empty are both valid cases. Who is giving that message?

Comment: btw. don't name a **single** double returnlist

Comment: It looks to me like returnList is just one double, not a list of anything.

Comment: I wonder how `returnList.Any()` should ever compile, as returnList seems to be a single double. You surely want to check for `returnsList` with s in the middle

Answer (score 0):

The Math.NET documentation says of the `Mean()` function:

https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Statistics/Statistics.htm#Mean

> Evaluates the sample mean, an estimate of the population mean. Returns NaN if data is empty or if any entry is NaN.

Neither the mean or Double.NaN are null, so `returnList` is never null, making the check for this redundant as proposed by ReSharper.

Comment: The returnrnlist is an array of double values passed to the method. There could be a possibility that the caller of the method might not pass the returnlist in that case you would be doing mean of nothing